# Executing contract function from another contract using it's hash

Tags: solidity, remix, hash

I am playing arround with smart contracts.
I have 2 contracts: `target` and `executer` (don't mind the name, it's just testing stuff).

`target` has just a simple function to change a string:

```
contract target {
    string public value = "lol";
    event SetValue(string);

    function setValue(string v) public {
        value = v;
        emit SetValue(v);
    }
}
```

From `executer`, I have a function to execute the `setValue` of target using an abstract and another function to execute `setValue` using the function's hash.

```
contract target {
   function setValue(string v) public;
}


    contract executer {

        target public tc;
        address public ta;
        function exeWithAbi(string value) public {
            tc.setValue(value);
        }

        function setAddress(address a) public {
            tc = target(a);
            ta = a;
        }

        function exeWithoutAbi(string v) public {
            require(ta.call(bytes4(keccak256("setValue(string)")),v));
        }
```

The function `exeWithAbi` works fine, but the function `exeWithoutAbi` does not work properly. It changes the value of the string, but sets it to nothing (empty string I think). According to the information provided by Remix (the details tab), the string I pass (`setValue(string)`) is correct (it is the correct function hash)

**Why is the value of my string not being set properly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `abi.encode` should work, although I'm not 100% sure why. (I don't understand why that's not what `ta.call` is already doing.)

```
function exeWithoutAbi(string v) public {
    require(ta.call(bytes4(keccak256("setValue(string)")), abi.encode(v)));
}
```

Comment: As a note, `abi.encode` was implemented in 0.4.22 if I am not wrong?

Comment: @EliDrion I have no reason to doubt that. :-)

Comment: Not a note for you, but for people who might use older versions and wonder why it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because a string is encoded differently than bytes32, so it won't work through using the `call` method, because you have to the ABI encoding yourself. It will work for other types such as `uint` or `bool`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it is true. Any way I could do this with strings?

Comment: For the `call`, probably, but you will need to search about it. You should stick to using the abstract contract, it's better.

Comment: Well, my purpose in long terme is to not having to use the abstract contract ^^

Comment: But why tho? There is literally no downside of using the abstract contract.

Comment: How does `bytes32` relate to anything? Does `call` cast its parameters to `bytes32` before ABI-encoding? (See my answer for a fix, but I don't fully understand it.)

Comment: I think he means that most other data types are implicitly zero padded to a multiple of 32 bytes when they are used in call(). Without your fix, the string was directly concatenated the function selector in my test.

Comment: I am getting puzzled too, I thought I found the reason, but no so sure now. I compared the input data using Andromelus code and @smarx's solution, and they are both the same.

Comment: Not for me. [Here](https://gist.github.com/mafrasi2/6d1e3af9e1b637ffba40bf9252be827d) is a hex dump for the message of the internal transaction. `93a09352` is the same as it's the function selector, but everything else is very different.

Comment: Yeah, for me they're different too. (Try logging `msg.data` to see.)

Comment: @mafrasi2 The abstract code does not cost gas when deployed? It is not considered as data passed to the chain during deployment?

Comment: @Andromelus no, definitely not. It's just used for the compilation, but it's gone in the bytecode. I just tested how much gas it needs and it's actually **cheaper** to use the interface instead of the manual method, since the function selector is already calculated during compilation. In your manual method, it's calculated each time you execute `exeWithoutAbi()`, which costs gas and needs more instructions.

Comment: Ok thanks. My method in better in my use case, but yours' better in the public environment